# NotificationListenerService doesn't detect missed calls notification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I'm using **NotificationListenerService** to detect when there's a new notification and when it's cleared. It works fine for all apps except for when there's a missed call notification, it doesn't detect it. How to solve this?

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d("+*+*","Notification Posted: " + sbn.getPackageName();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d("+*+*","Notification Removed: " + sbn.getPackageName()
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".NotificationService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone state permission is needed for notification listener to detect the missed call notification.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```